# Hard disk space not getting detected while reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 after a failed installation

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

While installing Ubuntu 16.04, sysyem got stuck and had to force restart. This was after formatting and repartioning the drive.

Reinstall isn't working showing that there is no space left for installation, eventhough I have a 1 TB hard disk which is supposed to be entirely free. Please help me in finding the lost space and in reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: I would suggest booting your Ubuntu install media selecting 'try ubuntu', then running `gparted` and examine your drive. If you have no wanted data on the drive, I would just delete everything, then create the partitions you want (eg. *part* for '/', *part* for '/home' etc), then exit gparted, click 'install ubuntu' and using the  'something else' option install it to your pre-prepared partitions...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did as you said, however, I still only see 30 GB out of the 1 TB disk space. Also, `gparted` doesn't allow me to create the parts for '/' or '/home' with logical partitioning and when I try with primary partitioning, it throws an error in "clear old file system signatures in  /dev/sda3".